# Apache 2.4 + PHP CGI SAPI: separate access_log of requests hitting PHP processing?

Tags: php, logging, apache-2.4

It's hard to tell from Apache general `access_log` which requests are processed by PHP, because direct file hits muddy the waters.

PHP FPM SAPI has a super useful `access_log` directive, but how do I get the same effect using PHP CGI SAPI?

PHP and Apache level solutions are both fine.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't even hinted your OS, I assume you're on UNIX-type system.

One easy to implement and universal way is to grep your general access log regularily with ie. *cron*. If you extend your question and provide sample log lines I could help with finding a correct regexp and command. Things to take into account here are logrotate (avoid loosing some logs on rotate) and a need to grep with low priority (avoid generating spikes of high load).

I use the above method to provide log snippets for our web developers and it haven't fallen short yet.